# Considering time in DBSCAN

Tags: python, dbscan

I want to cluster some GPS points with DBSCAN algorithm and I select eps:20 m and min_samples:4.
The algorithm works fine on my data, however I need to also consider time of point in the clustering process.
Suppose there are 10 points in a cluster, however 4 of them are between 8 am and 8:30 am and others in duration of 11 am and 11:15 am. What I want is that the algorithm detects 2 clusters here, one with time of 8 points and one with time of 11 points.
I mean I need to have another criteria for my DBSCAN algorithm rather than eps and min_samples.

Comment: No, you made a 3d point (lat, long, time) and try to cluster based on that

Comment: @DaniMesejo I thought about this however I am wondering what would be the unit of distance in a 3d point of (lat,long,time)? since I want the eps to be 20 meters.

Comment: What is the criteria for time?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I need the algorithm not only consider the distance between points but also the time of occurrence... the neighbor points should also in a specific time range.

Comment: Yes I understood that, but you said you need 20 meters for the distance between points, what should be the value for that *specific time range*

Comment: Also this question as of right now is to broad for the standard of SO, please add input and expected output and also the code you are using

Comment: @DaniMesejo oh sorry...you're right.... time range should be at most 5 minutes.

Comment: @DaniMesejo ok I try to gather more info and edit my question...

Answer (score 0):

Use Generalized DBSCAN.

Then define neighbors as being *both*

1. within distance maxNeighborDistance km
2. within maxNeighborTime minutes